# How do I make a object rotate around the center of the screen towards the mouse in unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, geometry, rotation

So I know it sounds confusing but its kind of simple.
Here's the issue:
I want to use `transform.RotateAround()` and have the player that is rotating around the center of the screen go towards the mouse.
note that this is in Unity C# 2D

```
 __
/  \
|  |
\__/
```

thats the circle the player rotates around
o = the circle

```
 __
/  \
|   o   (if the mouse is right here then the player should go where the o is)
\__/
```

sorry about the poor explanation its pretty complicated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class hareketkodları : MonoBehaviour
{
    //Classic Movement Codes // 
    public float YourPlayerSpeed = 8.2f;
    public Rigidbody2D Rigidb;
    Vector2 Movement_vc;

    //Right Here, the codes you want// 
    public Camera PlayerMouseCam;
    Vector2 PlayerMousePos; 
    void Update()
    {
        Movement_vc.x = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal"); //I'm writing here, classic movement methods   
        Movement_vc.y = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical"); //I'm writing here, classic movement methods   
           // =========== the codes you want ============ // 
        PlayerMousePos = PlayerMouseCam.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);  
    }

    void FixedUpdate() 
    {
        Rigidb.MovePosition(Rigidb.position + Movement_vc * YourPlayerSpeed * Time.fixedDeltaTime);  //I'm writing here, classic movement methods   
        // =========== the codes you want ============ // 
        Vector2 lookingDR = PlayerMousePos - Rigidb.position;
        float angle = Mathf.Atan2(lookingDR.y, lookingDR.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg - 90f;
        Rigidb.rotation = angle; 
    }
}
```

I Written For you :) I hope you make it happen, if you get stuck, text me or reach out.

Comment: This isn't quite what my question was but using this movement you have helped me completely improve my game and make it unique.